# Razor/ newbie: How do I show a partial view depending on results of a function call

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view that I wish to show in a page (using Razor) as a reult of some processing in a controller (and related utility function)

The partial needs to become visible, then after it has been used, I can redirect to the next stage in the flow.

How do I get the partial to become visible?

The workflow is analogous to this:

```
Load page

User enters some details and clicks 'check details' button

CheckDetails(formData):

    If details meet criteria, then 

    show PartialView A else

    show PartialView B
```

Thanks.

NJMUK

Comment: Are you targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core?

Comment: @virusstorm : Targeting .Net framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways this can be achieved and more options become available if you decided to use something like JQuery to achieve this. To do this purely with C# and Razor, you will want to do something like this.

In the controller, you will need two methods for the view:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DynamicDisplay()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DynamicDisplay(ActionsModel actionsModel)
{
    TempData.Add("DisplayGreeting", actionsModel.DisplayGreeting);
    TempData.Add("DisplayGenericMessage", actionsModel.DisplayGenericMessage);
    TempData.Add("ShowErrorMessage", actionsModel.ShowErrorMessage);
    return View();
}
```

In the `HttpGet` method, you simply return the view. In the `HttpPost` method, you need to use a model that captures the state/inputs from the user. From there you can either use the `TempData` dictionary (like my example) or another model to set conditions that you want evaluated in the Razor view.

In the view, you will need something like this:

```
@model DemoRazor.Models.ActionsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "DynamicDisplay";
}

<h1>Dynamic Display</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="DynamicDisplay">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="DisplayGreeting" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DisplayGreeting)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="DisplayGenericMessage" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DisplayGenericMessage)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="ShowErrorMessage" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShowErrorMessage)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


@if (TempData["DisplayGreeting"] != null && (bool)TempData["DisplayGreeting"])
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>Hello there!</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@if (TempData["DisplayGenericMessage"] != null && (bool)TempData["DisplayGenericMessage"])
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>This is a generic message</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@if (TempData["ShowErrorMessage"] != null && (bool)TempData["ShowErrorMessage"])
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>This is an error message</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here is the model I used for the view:

```
public class ActionsModel
{
    public bool DisplayGreeting { get; set; }
    public bool DisplayGenericMessage { get; set; }
    public bool ShowErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

You can then access the `TempData` dictionary in a code block using the `@` symbol. You will have access to the model(s) specified at the top of the page or any object accessible in the Razor context.

Comment: Hi. I notice that you are referencing a Model (DemoRazor.Models.ActionModel) but if you are using the TempData dictionary, will the @model reference not throw an exception at build time?

Comment: I just added the model I created for the example. You will need some sort of class (refereed to as a model in this case) to capture data/input from the user to do processing or conditional logic in the controller.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for your help.